# if else php checking several query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to make that if it does not find a row within the table, it goes to next query. The first 'if'($query1) works; however, its stuck on ($query2) and stopped there instead of going to $query3. Did I went wrong on the if else method?

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("testproject", $connection);
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mentors where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where username='$username'",$connection);
    $rows1 = (mysql_num_rows($query1)==1);
    $rows2 = (mysql_num_rows($query2)==1);
    $rows3 = (mysql_num_rows($query3)==1);
    if ($rows1) 
    {
            $query4=mysql_query("UPDATE mentors SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'",$connection);
            if($query4)
            {
                header("location: ../htmls/main_menu_m.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                exit();
            }
    }
    else if(!$rows1)
    {
        if($rows2) 
        {
            $query5=mysql_query("UPDATE students SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'",$connection);
            if($query5)
            {
                header("location: ../htmls/main_menu_s.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                exit();
            }
        }
        else if (!$rows2)
        {
            if ($rows3) 
            {
                $query6=mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'",$connection);
                if($query6)
                {
                    header("location: ../htmls/main_menu_a.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    header("location: ../index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not fetching any data everywhere. Some `if` statements only validate if the query itself was successful, not if it yielded any data.

Comment: you have a typo there `$query2=...; $query2=...;` should be `$query2=...; $query3=...;` I guess

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set a variable `$query3`.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("testproject", $connection);
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mentors where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where username='$username'",$connection);
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a little typo to me, Change:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where username='$username'",$connection);
```

to:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students where username='$username'",$connection);
    $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where username='$username'",$connection);
```

Comment: gee i didnt notice that. thanks guys!